# String.find not working for '.' (dot) character : corona SDK

Tags: android, string, character, coronasdk

I'm facing a problem with corona SDK.

When I'm searching for the index of `.` in a string, it is always returning `1` (even if the string does not contains `.`). I can't figure out what the real problem is. My code is as follows:

```
 local myString = "123.456"
 local dotIndex = string.find(myString, ".");
 print(dotIndex ) -- always returns 1 even if myString  dosen't contains a '.'
```

Am I wrong somewhere? Any advice is appreciable...
Thanks...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`find()` uses a pattern syntax.  A dot represents "any character."  This will match the first character of any string you search.  In order to search for a literal dot, you need to to this:

```
local dotIndex = string.find(myString, "%.");
```

[Here is the pattern documentation.](http://developer.coronalabs.com/content/strings#Patterns)